# в каких случаях ast.fix_missing_locations() меняет дерево?

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь найти пример, в котором посещение наследника `NodeTransformer` будет отличаться от посещения наследника `NodeTransformer` и использования `fix_missing_locations` в дереве.

Вот пример из документации (который по какой-то причине не работает, т.е. **дерево не меняется** в зависимости от того, применяем мы `fix_missing_locations` или нет):

```
from ast import *


class RewriteName(NodeTransformer):

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        return Subscript(
            value=Name(id='data', ctx=Load()),
            slice=Constant(value=node.id),
            ctx=node.ctx
        )


tree = parse('foo', mode='eval')
new_tree = fix_missing_locations(RewriteName().visit(tree))
new_uncorrected_tree = RewriteName().visit(tree)

new_tree_str = dump(new_tree, include_attributes=True)
new_uncorrected_tree_str = dump(new_uncorrected_tree, include_attributes=True)

print(new_tree_str == new_uncorrected_tree_str)  # True
```